# How to pass Dropdown choice values in Gravity Forms redirect

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm passing parameters from a Gravity Form to another page using a Confirmation of type Redirect.

Currently the Label of the dropdown choice gets passed, but I want to pass the Value instead. Does anyone know of a way of doing this?

My query string looks like this...

```
choice={Dropdown Field Name:6}
```

... which outputs a redirects URL like this...

```
https://example.com/result_page?choice=First+Choice
```

... but ideally it should look like this...

```
https://example.com/result_page?choice=1
```

Any ideas?

BTW I have obviously have the "show values" setting turned on for the Dropdown in GF, and numerical values set for each choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, merge tags for choice-based fields return the label but you can request the value with the `:value` modifier:

```
{Dropdown Field Name:6:value}
```

More details and other modifiers are available in the [Gravity Forms docs](https://docs.gravityforms.com/field-merge-tags/#:%7E:text=List%3A5%3Aurl%7D-,%3Avalue,-Applies%20only%20to).

Comment: Thanks Dave! For some reason the GF docs never came up when I searched in Google.

Comment: Been there, my friend! Sometimes you just don't know the right terms to find what you're looking for. 